# What is the derivative of $\frac{d}{d\alpha}Tr(A^T(\alpha)BA(\alpha))$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

Is the derivative of $Tr(A^T(\alpha)BA(\alpha))$ given by $\frac{d}{d\alpha}A(\alpha).2BA^T(\alpha)$, using the chain rule, or is it something else? I was expecting it to be a scalar valued function. This is where am stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the derivative
$$G = \frac{dA}{d\alpha}$$
is known.

Write the function in terms of the [Frobenius (:) Inner Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product)
and take its differential
$$\eqalign{
 f &= A:BA \cr\cr
df &= dA:BA + A:B\,dA \cr
   &= (B+B^T)A:dA \cr
   &= (B+B^T)A:G\,d\alpha \cr\cr
\frac{df}{d\alpha} &= (B+B^T)A:G \cr
   &= {\rm tr}(G^T(B+B^T)A) \cr
}$$
The result is scalar-valued, as you suspected.